# how to program player movement with new unity input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've never programmed movement before, I just use the rigid body first-person controller normally. I have no idea what to do when it comes to player movement

Comment: I would just search you find a lot of good tutorials that explains he basics of the new Unity Input System. Here as an example a Video of Brackeys which makes in my opinion some of the best unity tutorials available for free https://youtu.be/Pzd8NhcRzVo

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please review this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Here is a video by Brackeys, on first person movement: https://youtu.be/_QajrabyTJc. He also made a video about on third person movement: https://youtu.be/4HpC--2iowE. Though his movement system doesn't use physics. If you want a physics based movement system, you can use Dani's Karlson movement script: https://github.com/DaniDevy/FPS_Movement_Rigidbody He also made a video on it if your still confused: https://youtu.be/XAC8U9-dTZU